# What does MSDN refer with 'app'? Compile Winforms and WPF with .NET native

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, compilation, native

Please bear with to help me figure out what I'm missing: I've been searching for some information about .NET native but I'm not clear about MSDN when says:

> .NET Native is a precompilation technology for building and deploying
>   Windows apps that is included with Visual Studio 2015. It
>   automatically compiles the release version of apps that are written in
>   managed code (C# or Visual Basic) and that target the .NET Framework
>   and Windows 10 to native code.

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Sorry about my ignorance but wich type of applications are refering to?

For example: I've got an application developed in WPF so if I compile the app in Release with the new version of Visual Studio 2015 (changing framework 4.6) will it use the .NET native improving the application performance?

When does it refer with app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mention about targeting Windows 10 and by this they mean Universal Windows Apps right now. .NET Native packs used parts of .NET in resulting binaries, but this is only possible with .NET Core framework and currently, there are only 3 kinds of apps that run on .NET Core: UWP, ASP.NET 5 and Console Apps.

WPF still requires full .NET Framework to run. Whether other apps will be supported one day is still a question.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i want to know